# How to redirect user by their ip location

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I get the users IP and determine its location and then redirect them to a specific location of website?

My site is using Nuxt.js and nuxt-i18n module.

The website has 2 languages which are English and Turkish.

My address for Turkish part would be `http://localhost:3000/tr` which I want the user to be redirected here if he is from Turkey.

I have not found any solution for how to get user IP in Nuxt.js middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that helps, but in my case, using i18n I get user language using [NavigatorLanguage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) then set language system to his language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case this isn't what the client wants